# Holding Values in an object for console application C#

Tags: c#, oop, console-application, session-variables

I am currently writing an application where I am getting data from the DB and passing it to the object which will later be used to send the data off else where.  The issue I am having in testing is that the data doesn't hold in the object as when it is used later, I get null value errors.  I know we can store these in sessions, but I also know you can use objects and have done it before at previous jobs, but do not recall what I am missing to maintain the information.  Would I need to pass the object(s) from method to method until the job is done?

the first sample here shows where it is prepping the object.

```
 public void FtpInitialize()
    {
        _LogController.LogToFile(ValidateMessage.BeginInitialization);

        //Loading FTPClient object with ClientInfo Object data we got from DataBase.  FTPClient object is the object that sends the data.
        _LogController.FTPTraceLogToFile();
        ClientInfo = _RepositoryController.GetClientInfo(ClientInfo);
        if (ClientInfo == null)
            ClientInfo.ClientDataExists = false;
        else
        {
            FTPClient.Host = ClientInfo.Host;
            FTPClient.Port = ClientInfo.Port;
            FTPClient.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit;
            FTPClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ClientInfo.UserName, ClientInfo.Password);
            FTPClient.DataConnectionType = FtpDataConnectionType.EPSV; //according library documentation, auto passive is broken as of 10/20/2016
            FTPClient.EnableThreadSafeDataConnections = ClientInfo.EnableThreadSafeConnection;
            FTPClient.DataConnectionConnectTimeout = ClientInfo.DataConnectionTimeout;
            FTPClient.DataConnectionReadTimeout = ClientInfo.DataReadTimeout;
            FTPClient.ConnectTimeout = ClientInfo.ConnectionTimeout;
            FTPClient.ReadTimeout = ClientInfo.ReadTimeout;
            FTPClient.SocketPollInterval = ClientInfo.SocketPollInterval;
            FTPClient.SocketKeepAlive = ClientInfo.KeepSocketAlive;
            FTPClient.ValidateCertificate += new FtpSslValidation(OnValidateCertificate);

            _LogController.LogToFile(ValidateMessage.ClientDataLoaded);
            ClientInfo.ClientDataExists = true;
        }
    }
```

then below when I hit this part, it shows as null

```
 public bool SendData()
    {
        short errorCount = 0;
        using (FTPClient)
        {
            if (ClientInfo.ClientDataExists)
            {
```

Comment: Can you add a code sample which demonstrates what you're trying to do?

Comment: How do you know that the object is being populated from the DB?

Comment: sure I can provide a sample, as far as how do i know it is being populated, when I run my test, my method that loads the information to the object is populated but the information is dropped outside of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are using local variables in your methods. This is why the data "disappears".

For example if you are pulling data from your database you should have some kind of model class and container so that the data can persist until you are done with it.

EX: You have a database that contains information on people (name, dob, etc).

You should have a class that defines person and possibly a List to store said people. You call your database and pull X person objects into your List variable. You then can pass your List into the methods. Note: You can ditch the List (or whatever collection you use) if you are doing it one at a time.

The implementation of this really depends on how you want the objects to persist. If you know you will only pull one person object at a time you can declare var databasePerson  from the database. Use the List if you will be pulling more information and then pop off the object when your are down with it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: oh! I do believe the list part is what I am missing.  I do have everything else as you explained for the most part, just not into a list but rather directly into the instantiated object.  I guess the object doesn't hold globally?

Comment: @ggiaquin it depends where you declare the object.

If this is the workflow. DB -> object -> DoWork -> Repeat. No longer need object. Declare a variable in your mainwindow.cs that has scope throughout the class. If the

if the workflow is DB -> object -> DoWork in parallel with multiple calls. Declare a list and have the objects added to the list, array, etc. 

But in either case, you need to define the object or list at the beginning of mainwindow so that its scope is throughout the project. EX: `public List <Person> = new List <Person>();`